# How to download a bazaar repository with revision history without using the "bzr" Command Line Interface?

Tags: bazaar, launchpad

I tried downloading the bazar repository from launchpad with revision history using:

```
bzr branch lp:<repo-name>
```

This repository includes the **.bzr** directory which contains the revision history.
However **launchpad.net** also shows an option of downloading the zip file for some repositories.
The zip file does not contain the **.bzr** directory. It just contains the source snapshot of the latest version.

In github it is possible to download zip files with complete git revision history (ie. the **.git**  directory is present)

I was wondering if this is possible in Launchpad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I don't think Launchpad has such feature. The zip files you see are packaged by the project owners, not something generated or automatic. They could package zip files including the full history but the purpose is usually the opposite: a release version of the project with no history, only the files.

If you want a zipped version of the full history, you have to do it in two steps: branch and then zip up.

The `--no-tree` flag might be useful for you. Using that flag with the `branch` command will create only the `.bzr` directory without the working tree (the project files).